# How to do Flask REST api key validation without decorators?

Tags: rest, flask

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to accomplish the following:

For all of the subroutes of a particular route I want to extract a parameter and validate that an api key has been provided either by GET param or Header key.

The ideal would be if I could nest blueprints. Then I would do something like following:

Have a main blueprint to pull the parameter and validate the api key:

```
@secured_api.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_tenant(endpoint, values):
    g.tenant_code = values.pop('tenant')

@secured_api.before_request
def validate_api_key():
    api_key = request.headers.get('X-Api-Key')
    ...
    if (api_key is None):
        raise InvalidApiKey()
```

Then, having another blueprint with my resources (v1_bp) I could do:

```
secured_api.register_blueprint(v1_bp, url_prefix="/v1")
app.register_blueprint(secured_api, url_prefix='/secured/<tenant>')
```

So that all of v1_bp routes would be under /secured//v1

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain your problem more, it's not clear.

Comment: @itmard: In short I want every subroute under a particular route to check the validity of the provided api key.

say, everything under /secured I want to always check for api key.

And I want to hang multiple bluerprints off that root route.

/secured/bp1/..routes
/secured/bp2/..routes

Something like that

Comment: If this were express (nodejs) I could attach an "api key validator" middleware to /secured. And hang off the rest of my routes on /secured as well. But I can't do that with flask, so I was wondering what the best approach for doing something like this with Flask would be.